WSO2, an API for OAuth
I’m working on a solution to set up an API in the gateway that external vendors can use for OAuth. We do not want external vendors to have access to the APIM, so we are thinking about building an API that external apps can consume. I’m new to WSO2 and would like to know your thoughts or if there is a better solution to achieve this.

Once option is, you could create application[1] and subscribe to the API[2] and generate oauth keys[3] . You could share these keys with the vendors so that they could generate access tokens and invoke the API. external parties won't have to login. You could check the official documentation to see what kind of additional features (security, throttling, etc) you could use to build a solution.
[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.3.0/consume/manage-application/create-application/
[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.3.0/consume/manage-subscription/subscribe-to-an-api/
[3] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.3.0/consume/manage-application/generate-keys/generate-api-keys/
[4] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.3.0/consume/consume-api-overview/
